# Update query changing value I set

Tags: vba, ms-access

My code is below for Access 2010.  This is for a simple password reset form. I tell it what to set the password to, but when I got look in the table the value is "9.63258661963259E+44"  it changed the integer to a decimal.  Why is that happening?

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub cmdPasswordReset_Click()

Dim dbre As Database
Dim qre As QueryDef

Set dbre = CurrentDb
empID = Me.cmbEmpPassChange

sqlString = "Update Employee"
sqlString = sqlString + "SET Password = 963258661963258661963258661963258661963258661 "
sqlString = sqlString + " where ID = " & empID & ";"

dbre.Execute sqlString, dbFailOnError

End Sub
```

Comment: That's not changing the number it's just a different way of representing it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 0):

It's not a decimal but an exponential (scientific) representation.

However, set it as a string and bracket the field name as it is a reserved word:

```
sqlString = sqlString & " SET [Password] = '963258661963258661963258661963258661963258661'"
```